# Token support on the menu link field

Tags: navigation, tokens

Is there is any alternative way to make token to work in the Drupal 8 menu link field other than Menu Token module. I want to use token to set as a default value when I am creating new menu, but if I am using Menu Token module, first, I don't see any option in the node form to enable the token menu. Secondly, I have to manually enable the token option for each menu item under Admin-> Menu after creating a node which I don't want to do.

I am trying this in Drupal 8, any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: The alternative way is to create your own custom module that adds token support.

Comment: Hi, I created my own token module but when I am using that token on the menu title field its working, if I put the same token on the description field its not working.